# Div not displaying proprerly

Tags: css, html

**html**

```
<body>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
body{
  height:100%
}
.left{
  float:left;
  background-color:#ccffcc;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
}
.right{
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  background-color:#ffcc99
}
```

I've set the parent element's height

What do I have to do to see my two divs ?

It seems to only work when I use pixels but I dislike using pixels...

Comment: for starters....`html` should be `<html>`..

Comment: You have to write some text in HTML tags of DIV

Comment: <html>

<head>
 <title>untitled</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 
 <link href="css2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 
 
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>

</body>

</html>         I tried to shorten it for the question

Answer (score 1):

Add `height:100%` to html as well

```
body, html{
height:100%
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EJIgIcac/2/edit)**

Answer (score 1):

```
body,html{
height:100%
}
```

I just edited this part alone, i.e added html

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qw8HN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LZsXF/)

add :

```
body, html {
    height:100%
}
```

**ALSO**...you have incorrect tag for `html`, use `<html>`

Comment: that was just for shortening purposes

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</body>
<html>



<style>

body,html{
height:100%
}
.left
{
float:left;
background-color:#ccffcc;
height:100%;
width:50%;
}
.right
{
height:100%;
width:50%;
float:right;
background-color:#ffcc99
}
</style>
```

Hope This Helps :)

Comment: Now you can fiddle it and check :):)

Comment: that's gud you have added 100% to the html..!! so please check before answering dont mislead them

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>


        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>

    </body>


    <style>

    body{
    `height:100%
    }
    .left
    {
    float:left;
    background-color:#ccffcc;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    }
    .right
    {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    background-color:#ffcc99
    }
    </style>
    </html>
```

Comment: How about this one `height:100% ?

Comment: just go to site http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro                and copy paste the code

Comment: have you heard about http://www.w3fools.com/ please dont quote w3schools from now.

Comment: and may i know what is the difference between your code and the author's code, i dont see any differences

Comment: i am not quoting any site please read and then reply smart ass

Answer (score 0):

if you have any issue in this css. you can also use inline css `<body style="height:100%">`
Because may be its a css conflict issue.

```
<body style="height:100%">


        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>

    </body>


    <style>
    html{
       height:100%;        
   } 

    .left
    {
    float:left;
    background-color:#ccffcc;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    }
    .right
    {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    background-color:#ffcc99
    }
    </style>
```

Updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xNePD/)

Comment: copy and run this file into your local machine. its working good @Amarnath Balasubramanian

Comment: u have added html 100% to the code, that works..!! gud, so before answering double check it..!